# Unable to navigate to community page using <lightning:navigation

Tags: javascript, navigation, lightningnavigation

I am using a `<lightning:verticalNavigation>` which calls a method to redirect to a Lightning Community page.

**Component**

```
<lightning:navigation aura:id="navService" />

<lightning:verticalNavigation onselect="{! c.handleClick }">
    <lightning:verticalNavigationSection label="My Account">
        <lightning:verticalNavigationItem label="My Profile" name="my-profile" 
    </lightning:verticalNavigationSection>
</lightning:verticalNavigation>
```

**Controller**

```
handleClick: function (cmp, event, helper) {

    var selected = event.getParam('name');

    var navService = cmp.find("navService");

    var pageReference = {
        type: 'standard__navItemPage',
        attributes: {
            "apiName": "/my-profile"
        }
    };

    navService.navigate(pageReference)
},
```

Yet, the page does not redirect.

**Questions**

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: Last I had known this does not work in communities.

Comment: Using `$A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");` opens the page in a new window...

Answer (score 3):

Looks like as a part of summer19 release (https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_networks_navigationenhancements.htm), for communities the navigation can be achieved using below

```
handleClick: function (cmp, event, helper) {

var selected = event.getParam('name');

var navService = cmp.find("navService");

var pageReference = {
    type: 'comm__navItemPage',
    attributes: {
        "apiName": "/my-profile"
    }
};

   navService.navigate(pageReference)
},
```

Note that you can also use `$A.get("e.force:navigateToURL")`

For not opening in the new window use the relative url

Comment: Thanks. But I used the relative URL and it still opened in a new tab/window.